# Remove files from dropzone on bootstrap modal close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropzone.js, dropzone

When I upload the image using dropzone then the image name will be displayed. When I closed the modal then I want to remove the last uploaded image.

**Problem**

How I manually trigger **removedfile** function [example link](https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/OvrmJr?editors=1010)

**Code**

```
 // open create folder modal
    $('.js-upload-file-btn').on('click',function () {
        $(".js-upload-file, .modal-backdrop").addClass("open");
    });

    // close all modal
    $(document).on('click','.modal .close',function () {
        $(".modal, .modal-backdrop").removeClass("open");
 
    });


    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    try {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone" , {
            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: .5, // MB

            addRemoveLinks : true,
            dictDefaultMessage :
                '<span class="bigger-150 bolder"><i class=" fa fa-caret-right red"></i> Drop 
                files</span> to upload \
                <span class="smaller-80 grey">(or click)</span> <br /> \
                <i class="upload-icon fa fa-cloud-upload blue fa-3x"></i>'
            ,
            dictResponseError: 'Error while uploading file!',

            //change the previewTemplate to use Bootstrap progress bars

        });
    } catch(e) {
      //  alert('Dropzone.js does not support older browsers!');
    }
```

Comment: Hi, use `myDropzone.removeAllFiles( true );` inside `$(document).on('click','.modal .close',function () {` .Also put this event after dropzone code .